# HTTP Proxy server is not able to collect entire response from host server in C

Tags: c, http, get, proxy-server

I am implementing an HTTP proxy-server in C.
I am getting the HTTP request header from the brownser(client) and parsing it to find url,portnumber and so on. Then I am making a request to the remote server in the following format:
  **GET / HTTP1.0\r\nHost: www.gmail.com:80\r\n\r\n**
But during execution, the proxy server is not able to read entire date from the remote server.
 
Is it problem with header from proxy server to remote server or reading data from server.

```
 void handle_connection(......)
{
    ......
   //request send from proxy to remote server
      sprintf(buffer, "%s %s HTTP/1.%d\r\nHost: %s:80\r\n\r\n"
     , http_args[0], requested_url->file, requested_url->proto, requested_url->host);
          //sending the request to remote server connection socket rfd
    n = write(rfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
          //reading data from the response of the server
    while ((n = read(rfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
        write(connfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE); //sending it to client web brownser
        bzero(buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    }
    close(rfd);
}
```

Comment: what problem? unable to send? error response from remote(host) server?

Comment: Web brownser is showing error or blank page. It is taking more time to load. I am able to get the response from the Remote server. But on writing it on to the client connection socket (connfd) web brownser is not able to display data.

Comment: can you take tcpdump between client and proxy; also between proxy and server. Analise the packets exchanged using tools like wire-shark? See if the page can be accessed without proxy.

Comment: The problem is that Remote server is not waiting until it is received by Proxy . Getting Connection Reset by peer error after reading some data

Comment: Have you tried any static webpage without inherent redirection? like [simple page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html)

Comment: Ya. Some times its displaying some data and some times brownser is displaying blank page. Or else it is stuck in loading.